# How to make the Android app load into logo then back to main activity?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am new to App Development and I've been studying Kotlin for only a month now (1 hour everyday). I got the grasp of the functions but I still haven't gotten around using them for the purposes I have in mind.

Using Android Studio, I am trying to make the App load into a logo upon opening the app(Just like Facebook, Reddit), the logo is animated (which is not a problem for me). I have a couple of ways to achieve this but I wanna see what's the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new SplashActivity and change your starting activity in you manifest file like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then in your SplashActivity's OnCreate, start your MainActivity

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
```

You can read more about this [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154).

Answer (score 0):

You can create one `Activity` let's say `SplashActivity` which will have your logo and animations you want. Then from that `Activity` you can start your `MainActivity`. If you need to process some data inside your `SplashActivity` you do that then you start `MainActivity`. Otherwise, if you don't have any data to process you can simply start `MainActivity` with some delay, like this:

```
 Handler().postDelayed({
            val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }, 5000)
```

This will start your `MainActivity` after 5000 milliseconds which is 5 seconds. Now try to write some code and if you run into a problem try to find a solution or ask again if you can't. There is a lot of tutorials on the Internet you can find on how to do this.

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding @Sphax